# Firefox XUL + jQuery + jQuery UI + SelectToUiSlider

Tags: jquery, firefox, xul

I've successfully managed to deploy jQuery in a Firefox extension that creates an overlay. I decided to add jQuery UI which I had no problem with until I used a jQuery extension that in itself builds upon the jQuery UI Slider. I'm using the selectToUISlider which you can see here: http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/slider_v2/index.php, and the code here: http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/slider_v2/js/selectToUISlider.jQuery.js

Problem is that when I use the selectToUISlider jquery extension I keep getting a 'div is null' error from jquery.js Can anyone possibly point me in the right direction on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an issue with dynamic HTML in XUL using jQuery and more specifically with references to **div.innerHTML**. This issue has been addressed quite well here: http://digitalmihailo.blogspot.com/2008/05/jquery-and-dynamic-html-in-xul.html